# Prime order elements in $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

What is known about the elements of prime order $p$ in $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{Z})$?

All I know at this point is that $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{Z})$ has an element of prime order $p$ iff $p-1\leq n$ and that there are only finitely many conjugacy classes of such elements (Minkowski).

Comment: The theorem of Latimer and MacDuffee establishes a bijective correspondence between conjugacy classes of elements of order $p$ in $GL_{p-1}(\mathbb{Z})$ and ideal classes in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_p]$.

Comment: What sort of information do you need/want?

Comment: Curtis and Reiner's book has a nice description of integral $\mathbb Z /p$-representations.

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to get some kind of classification of all these elements/conjugacy classes as in Latimer MacDuffee's result but also for other $n$-values.

Comment: I think that Theorem 74.3 in Curtis and Reiner, Representation Theory of Finite Groups and Associative Algebras, does exactly this.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/27175/ contains a more detailed discussion of the integral representation theory result mentioned in nsrt's comment.